# How to combine both <select> and <input> by an aesthetic way?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, select, input

I work on a userscript (Greasemonkey/TamperMonkey), and I need to add a `<input>` in my drop-down list if ever an element is selected.

It is a way to make my `<select>` dynamic and interactive so that the user can add items by itself.

I would like visually, the user has the impresion that the `<input>` is an `<option>` in the `<select>`.

The only way I've found to do this is to reduce the width of `<select>` and display an `<input>`.

**HTML:**

```
<input style='display:none'></input>
<select id='my_select' style='width:150px'>
    <option>Test 1</option>
    <option>Test 2</option>
    <option>Test 3</option>
    <option>Make me feel input</option>
</select>
```

**Script:**

```
$('#my_select').change(function() {
    var choosen = $("select option:selected").text();

    if (choosen == 'Make me feel input') {
        $('input').attr('style','width:125px;border-right:0px');
        $('select').attr('style','width:24px;margin-left:-4px;border-left:0px')
    }
    else {
        $('input').attr('style','display:none');
        $('select').attr('style','width:150px');
    }
});
```

The result is pretty nice, [you can try it on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AnbmU/).

Unfortunately, because of `border-left:0px` and `border-right:0px` appearance is completely lost, and the style of the input and select become ugly.

[image: Yuck!] (Firefox)

Moreover, the final appearance depends on the browser used. With Chrome, for example, here's what happens: [image: Yuck²!]

So I wish I configure my input-select in order to make it look good regardless of the browser. Is it possible to simulate the appearance given by Firefox using CSS and JavaScript?

Of course, I thought about using a plugin like Chosen, SelectBoxIt ou Select2, but I do not think they are easily compatible with my input-select (because of the width resize for example).

Could you help me please?

Comment: If you are open to ideas, it's better if you use a *fully* custom select element. Otherwise, I see a maintenance nightmare coming up for you. Now, Seeing if any of those plugins is compatible with what you want to do is a task that you can easily undergo

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is an easier way without wrappers. You can set your input to `position:relative` and `display:inline-block` and then manipulate `margin` to position over the `select`.
Note that it is much easier to add input **after** select, which will make z-index hackery unnecessary.

See example here: http://jsfiddle.net/AnbmU/6/ I also took liberty to clean up your code from common mistakes.

**EDIT:** Actually, you don't even need `position:relative`. Not sure why I brought this up.

Comment: I was suffering for this issue at one of my project. It is a good solution. Thank you very much for that

Answer (score 0):

i visied the fiddle yuo provide in some browsers.
there is some problems and paradoxes:

> 1- when you click on select box, it opens (naturally) and when you
>   click on an input it activates and is ready to type in.   question is
>   how you want to handle this?
>
> 2- in your code when you reduce the select width it will open in a
>   shifted place wich is equall to your input width;

**finally answer**
you sholud put your input and select in a container(wrapper), and make it `position: relative`;
then comes yuor input with: `border: 0; position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; z-index: 2;` and `display: none`, when you want to activate it simply make it: `display: block;`
and it handles both above problems nicely

Answer (score 0):

A ui component that's frequently called a "combo box" has functionality similar to what you describe.

examples:

jquery
http://simpletutorials.com/?path=tutorials/javascript/jquery/ddcombobox
http://fairwaytech.com/flexbox/flexbox-demos/#demo1

dojo
https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dijit/form/ComboBox.html#dijit-form-combobox

cross-browser form element styling has always been a challenge. generally, ui toolkits just avoid the issue and totally recreate the ui components using lots of divs and explicit styles for reliability.

Answer (score 0):

you should try this : https://github.com/eredacokmerke/metal

also there is an example : codepen.io/eredacokmerke/pen/LEpNLg

from metal readme:

```
Metal is a pure javascript library that provides combination of select and input tag.

Usage

add css :
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://raw.githack.com/eredacokmerke/metal/master/metal.css">

add js :
<script src="https://raw.githack.com/eredacokmerke/metal/master/metal.js"></script>

add html for list with input:
<div class="metal-div">
    <div class="metal-input-div" metal-text="Choose..."></div>
    <div class="metal-items-div">
        <ul class="metal-items">
            <li>first_item</li>
            <li>second_item</li>
            ....
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>

add html for list without input:
<div class="metal-div">
    <div class="metal-output-div" metal-text="Choose..."></div>
    <div class="metal-items-div">
        <ul class="metal-items">
            <li>first_item</li>
            <li>second_item</li>
            ....
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8259) and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.